# How to view the FusionGroups in PyTorch JIT

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, jit

I am using `torch.jit.script` to convert a custom `LSTMCell` object into a `ScriptModule`. Code is given below for completeness (exact same as [Optimising RNNs PyTorch Blog Post](https://pytorch.org/blog/optimizing-cuda-rnn-with-torchscript/#writing-custom-rnns). While my overall code speed has increased, I would like to see the FusionGroups i.e., which operations got fused into one kernel.

I was expecting the operations involving `gates` would be fused into one kernel and it would show up as `CudaFusionGroup` when I run the `cell.graph_for` command.

Minimal code to reproduce:

```
from typing import Tuple
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torch.nn import Parameter
import torch.nn as nn


class LSTMCell(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.weight_ih = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, input_size))
        self.weight_hh = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size, hidden_size))
        self.bias_ih = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size))
        self.bias_hh = Parameter(torch.randn(4 * hidden_size))

    def forward(
        self, inpt: Tensor, state: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]
    ) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]:
        hx, cx = state
        gates = (
            torch.mm(inpt, self.weight_ih.t())
            + self.bias_ih
            + torch.mm(hx, self.weight_hh.t())
            + self.bias_hh
        )
        ingate, forgetgate, cellgate, outgate = gates.chunk(4, 1)

        ingate = torch.sigmoid(ingate)
        forgetgate = torch.sigmoid(forgetgate)
        cellgate = torch.tanh(cellgate)
        outgate = torch.sigmoid(outgate)
        cy = (forgetgate * cx) + (ingate * cellgate)
        hy = outgate * torch.tanh(cy)
        return hy, (hy, cy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = torch.device('cuda', 0)
    input_size, hidden_size, batch_size = 8, 8, 64
    inpt = torch.randn(batch_size, input_size, device=device)
    h = torch.randn(batch_size, hidden_size, device=device)
    cell = LSTMCell(input_size, hidden_size)
    cell.to(device)
    cell = torch.jit.script(cell)
    op = cell(inpt, (h, h))
    print(cell.graph_for(inpt, (h, h)))
    print(cell.code)
```

Output Obtained:

```
graph(%self : __torch__.LSTMCell,
      %inpt.1 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0),
      %state.1 : (Tensor, Tensor)):
  %hx.1 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0), %cx.1 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0) = prim::TupleUnpack(%state.1)
  %weight_ih : Float(32, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0) = prim::GetAttr[name="weight_ih"](%self)
  %bias_ih : Float(32, strides=[1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0) = prim::GetAttr[name="bias_ih"](%self)
  %weight_hh : Float(32, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0) = prim::GetAttr[name="weight_hh"](%self)
  %bias_hh : Float(32, strides=[1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0) = prim::GetAttr[name="bias_hh"](%self)
  %382 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0), %383 : Float(32, strides=[1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0), %384 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0), %385 : Float(32, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0), %386 : Float(32, strides=[1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0), %387 : Float(64, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=0, device=cuda:0), %388 : Float(32, 8, strides=[8, 1], requires_grad=1, device=cuda:0), %389 : bool = prim::RequiresGradCheck[types=[Tensor(requires_grad=0), Tensor(requires_grad=1), Tensor(requires_grad=0), Tensor(requires_grad=1), Tensor(requires_grad=1), Tensor(requires_grad=0), Tensor(requires_grad=1)]](%cx.1, %bias_hh, %hx.1, %weight_hh, %bias_ih, %inpt.1, %weight_ih)
  %390 : Tensor, %391 : Tensor = prim::If(%389)
    block0():
      %263 : Tensor, %379 : Tensor = prim::DifferentiableGraph_0(%382, %383, %384, %385, %386, %387, %388)
      -> (%263, %379)
    block1():
      %442 : Function = prim::Constant[name="fallback_function", fallback=1]()
      %443 : (Tensor, Tensor) = prim::CallFunction(%442, %cx.1, %bias_hh, %hx.1, %weight_hh, %bias_ih, %inpt.1, %weight_ih)
      %444 : Tensor, %445 : Tensor = prim::TupleUnpack(%443)
      -> (%444, %445)
  %58 : (Tensor, Tensor) = prim::TupleConstruct(%391, %390)
  %60 : (Tensor, (Tensor, Tensor)) = prim::TupleConstruct(%391, %58)
  return (%60)
with prim::DifferentiableGraph_0 = graph(%cx.1 : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %bias_hh : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %hx.1 : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %weight_hh : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %bias_ih : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %inpt.1 : Tensor(requires_grad=0),
      %weight_ih : Tensor(requires_grad=0)):
  %111 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::t(%weight_ih) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:23:27
  %105 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::mm(%inpt.1, %111) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:23:12
  %98 : int = prim::Constant[value=1]()
  %96 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::add(%105, %bias_ih, %98) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:23:12
  %396 : int[] = aten::size(%105) # <string>:3:44
  %397 : int[] = aten::size(%96) # <string>:3:55
  %398 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%396, %397) # <string>:3:19
  %399 : int[] = aten::size(%bias_ih) # <string>:3:93
  %401 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%399, %397) # <string>:3:68
  %402 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%398, %401)
  %self_size.28 : int[]?, %other_size.28 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%402)
  %90 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::t(%weight_hh) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:25:27
  %84 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::mm(%hx.1, %90) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:25:14
  %75 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::add(%96, %84, %98) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:23:12
  %403 : int[] = aten::size(%96) # <string>:3:44
  %404 : int[] = aten::size(%75) # <string>:3:55
  %405 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%403, %404) # <string>:3:19
  %406 : int[] = aten::size(%84) # <string>:3:93
  %408 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%406, %404) # <string>:3:68
  %409 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%405, %408)
  %self_size.30 : int[]?, %other_size.30 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%409)
  %gates.2 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::add(%75, %bias_hh, %98) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:23:12
  %410 : int[] = aten::size(%75) # <string>:3:44
  %411 : int[] = aten::size(%gates.2) # <string>:3:55
  %412 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%410, %411) # <string>:3:19
  %413 : int[] = aten::size(%bias_hh) # <string>:3:93
  %415 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%413, %411) # <string>:3:68
  %416 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%412, %415)
  %self_size.32 : int[]?, %other_size.32 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%416)
  %56 : Tensor(requires_grad=0), %57 : Tensor(requires_grad=0), %58 : Tensor(requires_grad=0), %59 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = prim::ConstantChunk[chunks=4, dim=1](%gates.2) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:28:48
  %ingate.9 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::sigmoid(%56) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:30:17
  %forgetgate.9 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::sigmoid(%57) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:31:21
  %cellgate.9 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::tanh(%58) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:32:19
  %outgate.9 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::sigmoid(%59) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:33:18
  %34 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::mul(%forgetgate.9, %cx.1) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:34:14
  %417 : int[] = aten::size(%forgetgate.9) # <string>:3:44
  %418 : int[] = aten::size(%34) # <string>:3:55
  %419 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%417, %418) # <string>:3:19
  %420 : int[] = aten::size(%cx.1) # <string>:3:93
  %422 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%420, %418) # <string>:3:68
  %423 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%419, %422)
  %self_size.34 : int[]?, %other_size.14 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%423)
  %27 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::mul(%ingate.9, %cellgate.9) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:34:34
  %424 : int[] = aten::size(%ingate.9) # <string>:3:44
  %425 : int[] = aten::size(%27) # <string>:3:55
  %426 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%424, %425) # <string>:3:19
  %427 : int[] = aten::size(%cellgate.9) # <string>:3:93
  %429 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%427, %425) # <string>:3:68
  %430 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%426, %429)
  %self_size.36 : int[]?, %other_size.34 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%430)
  %cy.2 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::add(%34, %27, %98) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:34:14
  %431 : int[] = aten::size(%34) # <string>:3:44
  %432 : int[] = aten::size(%cy.2) # <string>:3:55
  %433 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%431, %432) # <string>:3:19
  %434 : int[] = aten::size(%27) # <string>:3:93
  %436 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%434, %432) # <string>:3:68
  %437 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%433, %436)
  %self_size.38 : int[]?, %other_size.36 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%437)
  %13 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::tanh(%cy.2) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:35:23
  %hy.2 : Tensor(requires_grad=0) = aten::mul(%outgate.9, %13) # /home/raj/Projects/test.py:35:13
  %438 : int[] = aten::size(%outgate.9) # <string>:3:44
  %439 : int[] = aten::size(%hy.2) # <string>:3:55
  %440 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%438, %439) # <string>:3:19
  %441 : int[] = aten::size(%13) # <string>:3:93
  %443 : int[]? = aten::_size_if_not_equal(%441, %439) # <string>:3:68
  %444 : (int[]?, int[]?) = prim::TupleConstruct(%440, %443)
  %self_size.40 : int[]?, %other_size.38 : int[]? = prim::TupleUnpack(%444)
  return (%cy.2, %hy.2, %inpt.1, %111, %self_size.28, %other_size.28, %hx.1, %90, %self_size.30, %other_size.30, %self_size.32, %other_size.32, %ingate.9, %forgetgate.9, %cellgate.9, %outgate.9, %cx.1, %self_size.34, %ingate.9, %cellgate.9, %self_size.36, %other_size.34, %self_size.38, %other_size.36, %13, %outgate.9, %13, %self_size.40, %other_size.38)

def forward(self,
    inpt: Tensor,
    state: Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]]:
  hx, cx, = state
  weight_ih = self.weight_ih
  _0 = torch.mm(inpt, torch.t(weight_ih))
  bias_ih = self.bias_ih
  _1 = torch.add(_0, bias_ih)
  weight_hh = self.weight_hh
  _2 = torch.add(_1, torch.mm(hx, torch.t(weight_hh)))
  bias_hh = self.bias_hh
  gates = torch.add(_2, bias_hh)
  ingate, forgetgate, cellgate, outgate, = torch.chunk(gates, 4, 1)
  ingate0 = torch.sigmoid(ingate)
  forgetgate0 = torch.sigmoid(forgetgate)
  cellgate0 = torch.tanh(cellgate)
  outgate0 = torch.sigmoid(outgate)
  cy = torch.add(torch.mul(forgetgate0, cx), torch.mul(ingate0, cellgate0))
  hy = torch.mul(outgate0, torch.tanh(cy))
  return (hy, (hy, cy))
```

I see a `DifferentialGraph` but no `CudaFusionGroup`. Is this supposed to represent the Fusion Group?

When I change the weights & biases to simple tensors (i.e., not learnable), I can see a `CudaFusionGroup` forming for the `gates`.